# Google maps load when header is already loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I have codeigniter project which header, footer loading when calling the controller. So after header is loaded I want to add a google map to get latitude and longitude to textboxes when map been clicked. Currently I can do this outside of codeigniter. But I can't do this inside of CI after header loaded. I think its because google use window load function to initialize map.

```
<head>
<!-- Some js files loaded here when controller construct -->
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713956,-74.006653);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = event.latLng.lng();
})

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You're using jQuery, try something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // here paste google maps code
});
```

Map will initialize when DOM is ready